# How to put circle into middle of Frame by using methods getWidth and getHeight?

Tags: java, methods, colors, frame, geometry

I have a problem with put drawn circle into middle of Frame by using methods `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. I tried something with `Image` package but no idea where to implement this methods:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Circle extends Frame {

public Circle() {

    setSize(400,400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public Color() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 200, 200);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Circle c = new Circle();

    c.paint(null);
}
}
```

Then I have to use method `setColor(Color)` and `Color` class constructor to make random color of this circle (after every run of this program). I opened `Color` constructor but there is an error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to extract all the paint functionality to a `JComponent` here to take full advantage of Swing's optimized paint model using `paintComponent`.

The `Circle` is actually a `JFrame`. Inside in its constructor, a new component is created which handles the painting of the circle. The `Color` constructor has been removed as this is invalid syntax.

The circle co-ordinates are start in the top left-hand corner and take the full available width & height for drawing.

Also would recommend using lightweight Swing components over old-style AWT component.

```
public class Circle extends JFrame {

    public Circle() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        add(new CirclePanel());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c = new Circle();
    }
}

class CirclePanel extends JComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());  
    }
}
```

See: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Thanks, "could you only explain, why there is Circle object created?"  sorry , i get it now :)

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246351/creating-random-colour-in-java) for creating a random color.

Comment: Edited ^. So do I have to create class (Colors) like this?

Comment: Please don't change the code in the original question, it detracts from any answers given. If you want to create a new post, people are only too happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from within the `paint(...)` method and use the results returned for your `fillOval(...)` parameters.

But having said that, it's a better idea to draw in a Canvas that is added to the Frame. And having said that, it's much better still to draw in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel that is added to the contentPane of a JFrame in a Swing application.

Comment: @Reimeus: and ditto to you and your nice example!

Comment: Thanks! May You have tip for this random color at every single run?

Comment: @Fastkowy: create an array of allowed Colors, and then use a Random object to get an int no larger than the size of the array - 1 (simply `nextInt(myColorArray.length)`, and use that int to choose a Color from the array.