# Android marquee where each letter has different color

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple TextView marquee (inside a LinearLayout). I need each letter to have a different color. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? The text is pre-defined so I can hardcode everything if needs be. Here is my TextView

```
  <TextView
        style="@style/myFont"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:text="@string/my_text" />
```

Say the text is "Hello world! I am happy!"

Comment: the fastest is implementing custom ReplacementSpan http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ReplacementSpan.html

Comment: I have a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861612/only-one-of-many-marquees-working-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) and set the Text.

randomColor = https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246400/1008278

List of colors in XML >> https://gist.github.com/VenomVendor/6857539 modify to [StringArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

```
    String tempText = "Hello world! I am happy!"
    String[] tempTextArr = string.split("");
    String newText = "";
    String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_n);

    for(int i = 0; i < tempTextArr.length; i++ )
    {
        if(!tempTextArr[i].equals(" "))
        {
            newText = newText + "<font color='"+colors[i]+"'>"+tempTextArr[i]+"</font>"
            //newText = newText + "<font color='"+randomColor+"'>"+tempTextArr[i]+"</font>"
        }
        else{
            newText = newText + " ";
        }
    }

    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText));
```

Comment: Thanks! I might actually have to do this in the string resource file. But I am wondering how @pskink 's replacementSpan might work: looks like I can use array of color and for loop to reduce my work load and make the code reusable. Does anyone have an example of that?

Comment: I just saw your edit. I will try it. Thanks. +1 in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861612/only-one-of-many-marquees-working-on-android

Answer (score 2):

here you go:

```
class ColorSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    private LinearGradient shader;

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, FontMetricsInt fm) {
        float w = paint.measureText(text, start, end - start);
        int num = end - start;
        int[] colors = new int[num];
        float[] positions = new float[num];
        float cx = 0;
        float[] hsv = {
                0, 1, 1
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            float cw = paint.measureText(text, start+i, start+i+1);
            positions[i] = cx / w;
            cx += cw;
            hsv[0] = i * 360f / num;
            colors[i] = Color.HSVToColor(255, hsv);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getSize c " + Arrays.toString(colors));
        Log.d(TAG, "getSize p " + Arrays.toString(positions));
        Log.d(TAG, "getSize w " + w);
        shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, w, 0, colors, positions, TileMode.CLAMP);
        return (int) w;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        paint.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

test it in onCreate:

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextSize(40);
    SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello World!");
    ColorSpan what = new ColorSpan();
    b.setSpan(what, 0, b.length()-1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(b);

    setContentView(tv);
```