# Only one of many marquees working on android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

This is a follow up to question [Android marquee where each letter has different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860286/android-marquee-where-each-letter-has-different-color#20860386).

I actually have four of the TextViews mentioned, in three linear layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- ================================ Row 1 ================================ -->

    <LinearLayout style="@style/style1" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_1"
      style="@style/style2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:text="@string/text_1" />
        <!-- space -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_2"
      style="@style/style2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:text="@string/text_2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ================================ Row 2 ================================ -->

    <LinearLayout style="@style/style1" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_3"
      style="@style/style2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:text="@string/text_3" />
        <!-- space -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_4"
      style="@style/style2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:text="@string/text_4" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

In the code I have `setSelected(true)` for each TextView, yet only one of them is actually scrolling. The others show `...` for the overflow.

Comment: Post the whole layout.

Comment: well only one vuew can be selected

Comment: @pskink so is there a way to have multiple marquees running -- without having a background thread constantly looping setSelected.

Comment: hmmm, use a Handler plus scrollTo ?

Comment: What is the actual goal here?  You want the text to scroll on all of the views simultaneously?  If that's the case I think you might be better served extending TextView and applying your own animation code which doesn't rely on selection.

Comment: It may also be worth reconsidering your UI if the above is true.  I may have a wrong idea here, but as a User this would drive me totally nuts.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner good point. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that only the view which is focused on will show marquees correctly.