# How to get a different color each time I click?

Tags: java, random, switch-statement

I am currently trying to make a scenario where every time I click a JPanel it changes a different color each time. For example I don't want to click a magenta square and get a magenta square again.

```
Color newColor = null;

Color[] colorArr = {Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLACK,new Color (0x964B00),new Color (0xB57EDC)};
int ranNum = generator.nextInt(5);//generator is a .Random Object
switch (ranNum) {

    case 0:
    newColor = colorArr[0];
       break;

    case 1:
    newColor = colorArr[1];
       break;
    case 2:
    newColor = colorArr[2];
       break;
    case 3:
    newColor = colorArr[3];
       break;
    case 4:
    newColor = colorArr[4];
       break;
}
```

Comment: Why not just cycle through the colors instead of getting a random one each time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating random colour in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246351/creating-random-colour-in-java)

Comment: Add the colors to a `List`, shuffle the list and pop a color off the top each time till the list is empty - rinse and repeat

Comment: What is the need of switch case here? Why you are not just doing newColor  = colorArr[ranNum] ?

Answer (score 0):

you should define a global variable that holds the old color value.

```
int oldNum;
Color[] colorArr = {Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLACK,new Color (0x964B00),new Color (0xB57EDC)};

    void changeColor(){
        Color newColor = null;
        int ranNum;
        do{
            ranNum = generator.nextInt(5);//generator is a .Random Object
        }while(oldNum == ranNum);
        oldNum = ranNum;
        newColor = color[ranNum];
    }
```

Comment: How would I initialize oldNum?

Comment: @XanderDelpin its a primitive type, it wont be null in any circumstances. i forgot to change its value though, edited right now.

Comment: @XanderDelpin in the beginning, it will be -1, if you are curious.