# I'm trying to change the color of some of the blocks in my grid every 2 seconds

Tags: java, random, gridview, colors

I'm trying to change the color of some of the blocks in my grid every 2 seconds. So far, the blocks are just a set color (yellow), but I need them to automatically and randomly change color repetitively. This is the code so far; `g` is the grid.

```java
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillRect(wIncr * maxX / 2, 3 * hIncr, wIncr * (maxX / 2), hIncr * (maxY - 8));
g.setColor(Color.black);
```

I tried using a random generator:

```java
private static final int MIN_STATE_COLOR = STATE_RED;
private static final int MAX_STATE_COLOR = STATE_YELLOW;

int random = new Random().nextInt(MAX_STATE_COLOR - MIN_STATE_COLOR + 1) + MIN_STATE_COLOR;

g.setColor(Color.random);
g.fillRect(wIncr * maxX / 2, 3 * hIncr, wIncr * (maxX / 2), hIncr * (maxY - 8));
g.setColor(Color.black);
```

And that gave me an error with MIN_STATE_COLOR and MAX_STATE_COLOR.

I then also tried creating a timer:

```java
ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);  // I don't know how to make it random
    g.fillRect(wIncr * maxX / 2, 3 * hIncr, wIncr * (maxX / 2), hIncr * (maxY - 8));
    g.setColor(Color.black);
  }
};
int timerDelay = 3 * 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay, timerListener);
```

But this also gave me an error.

Comment: Specify your Java GUI framework: Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246418/21252090) method (or if you want it done in one line [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032024/21252090) method) to generate a random color. Here is how you can use **the first method** in your case.

```
ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener() {
    Random r = new Random();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Color c = new Color(
                r.nextFloat(),
                r.nextFloat(),
                r.nextFloat()
                );
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(wIncr * maxX / 2, 3 * hIncr, wIncr * (maxX / 2), hIncr * (maxY - 8));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
};
```

And here is **the second method**

```
ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener() {
    Random r = new Random();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
        g.fillRect(wIncr * maxX / 2, 3 * hIncr, wIncr * (maxX / 2), hIncr * (maxY - 8));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm having the issue "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable g defined in an enclosing scopeJava(536870937)" because it's saying the grid is under : Graphics g - clubSimulation.ClubView.paintComponent(Graphics)

Comment: Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: To fix this make a field `Graphics g` then set the value of `g`(field) to `paintComponent(Graphics g)` using `this.g = g`